# how to read every 2 lines from a file and put them in cell of a list

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have this out put :

```
PRODUCT NUMBER   : 2/CAX 105 7373                                                                                                                                                                                 
R-STATE          : R1A                                                                                                                                                                                            
PRODUCT NUMBER   : 14/CAX 105 9806                                                                                                                                                                                
R-STATE          : R1A                                                                                                                                                                                            
PRODUCT NUMBER   : 19/CAX 105 9770                                                                                                                                                                                
R-STATE          : R1A                                                                                                                                                                                            
PRODUCT NUMBER   : 32/CAX 105 4737                                                                                                                                                                                
R-STATE          : R1A
```

i need to put every 2 lines (product number and r-state in a list) it will be every

```
PRODUCT NUMBER   : 2/CAX 105 7373      
R-STATE          : R1A
```

is a case of a list

any help please
thank you !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this in Java, you can make use of an `ArrayList`, which is like Python's `list` in that it can have variable length.

```java
import java.io.*

public static ArrayList<String> readFile(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(filename));
    ArrayList<String> output = new ArrayList<String>();
    
    // counts every two lines
    int counter = 0;

    // note: this will break if your file has an odd number of lines
    while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
        String temp = scan.nextLine() + "\n" + scan.nextLine();
        output.add(temp);
    }

    return output;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
output = """
PRODUCT NUMBER : 2/CAX 105 7373
R-STATE : R1A
PRODUCT NUMBER : 14/CAX 105 9806
R-STATE : R1A
PRODUCT NUMBER : 19/CAX 105 9770
R-STATE : R1A
PRODUCT NUMBER : 32/CAX 105 4737
R-STATE : R1A
"""

# Split the output into lines
lines = output.strip().split('\n')

# Create the list by pairing every 2 lines
result_list = [(lines[i], lines[i+1]) for i in range(0, len(lines), 2)]

print(result_list)
```

Comment: thank you   for your response is there any way to it with the stream ?

Comment: This doesn't appear to be Java.